# Cancel Sublime Text multiple cursors in Vintage insert mode

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

**Question:**

Is there a way to add a new command (keyboard, I know clicking does this) to cancel multiline cursors, or maybe to remap the command mode to something than ESC so that it can be used for cancelling multiline cursors?

**Details:**

I really enjoy using sublime text, and recently found out about the vintage package you can use, where you have access to a modal text editor, similar to that of vim. I really enjoyed using that as well, but I keep running into this minor issue:

In sublime text w/o vintage mode, ESC can be used to turn off multiple line cursors (ctrl-alt-up/down for example). However, with vintage on, this brings me into command mode, but what I actually want is to stay in insert mode and cancel the multiline cursors.

I am interested to hear if anyone else ran into this, and what they did to fix it, as I feel it could be a fairly common thing to happen. Thanks!

**Answer**

Add a key binding (see accepted answer). I had to play around a bit with the settings in the accepted answer to get it working, but that is definitely the right way to go to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new key mapping. Go to **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** to open your custom keymap file. It needs to be valid [JSON](http://json.org), so if it doesn't have any contents yet, make sure that there is an open bracket `[` on the first line and a close bracket `]` on the last line. Individual key bindings are dicts surrounded by braces `{}` and separated by commas `,`.

Create a new entry with the following contents:

```json
    { "keys": ["shift+escape"], "command": "single_selection",
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
            { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false },
            {"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false}
        ]
    }
```

Basically what this does is create a key binding for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> that returns to a single selection only when in Insert mode, when a widget is not active, and when there are multiple selections. I chose that key combo because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, my first choice, seems to bring up the Metro Start Menu on Win8, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> is involved in window switching. Feel free to set it to whatever key binding you wish - the list of valid key names is [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys).

This should work with both Sublime Text 2 and ST3.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that solution. I pasted what you had, and it did not work until the `{ "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }` was changed to `{ "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": true }`. After that it worked fine. 

Could you expand a little on what the widget line is actually checking? Does this differ by the version of ST, or is it some system property? I am on w7 btw.